# view will move in iPhone6 standard display mood

Tags: ios, iphone-6

Here is my code:

```
#define VIEW_TOP_BAR 60 
scroll_View = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,VIEW_TOP_BAR, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - VIEW_TOP_BAR)];
```

It will add a scrollview into the viewcontroller, and it's ok in iPhone5 and iPhone6(zoomed display), but it looks like the scroll_view will be higher than it's right position.

Here is the same codes run in **zoomed** and **standard** view:

It's perfect in the zoomed iPhone6  or iPhone5, iPhone5s:

[image]

But, in standard iPhone6:

[image]

BTW, in my program, all the widgets is build in the storyboard except the scroll_view and the widgets in it.

Comment: Please reduce resolution of the images before uploading. Have you used auto-layouts?

Comment: @UmangBista, no, I didn't use the auto-layouts.

Comment: Since you are not using auto-layout,  you have to find the device on which app is running. And then, you have to hard-code define the co-ordinate(x , y) and size(w , h) of the view in question______ But I recommend you to use `autolayout` feature of Xcode, since it saves lot of code and time.

Comment: I guess your code is running in `-[UIView viewDidLoad]`. At that time, the view has not been resized to fit the device. E.g. add `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));` and watch for yourself.

Comment: @Mats , actually, my code is running in `viewDidAppear`.   @Umang Bista, what's more strange, I checked one of my app which using the same way to add scrollview, it just run in iPhone 4s/5/5s, but iPhone6, guess what? there is nothing wrong in iPhone 6, standard view, I'm truly confused

Comment: I solved it by adding a scroll view in storyboard, it's really strange